# ng2 cli extra serve tasks

Tags: angular, webpack

Is there any method to add custom tasks to the current version of ng2 cli?

For example watching on image changes and compressing them, linting etc?

I wanted to add spritesmith to generate sprites in the same "ng serve" task not calling extra npm scripts for watching but I have no idea if it is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your angular project you have npm scripts to run.

e.g. for the generated projects from `angular-cli`. you have

`npm start` which itself calls `ng serve`.

It will be better if you add your custom tasks, here in the

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "customTask": "<gulp task>"

}
```

You can change this scripts tasks to meet your requirements. like you can combine tasks using

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve | <gulp task>",
}
```

You can use `&&`, '|' and use `concurrently` to run more tasks.
Hope, this helps. 
It is not a better idea to mess with core `angular-cli`. leave that as it is.